# Generating new columns as a full-combination of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Could not find similar cases here.
Suppose, i have a DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,2,1,2],
                   'B':[2,2,3,3],
                   'C':[3,3,3,4],
                   'I':[1,0,0,1],
                   'II':[0,1,0,1]})
```

So it is:

```
    A   B   C   I   II
0   2   2   3   1   0
1   2   2   3   0   1
2   1   3   3   0   0
3   2   3   4   1   1
```

I want to make a full pairwise combination between {`A`,`B`,`C`} and {`I`,`II`}, so i get {`I-A`,`I-B`,`I-C`,`II-A`,`II-B`,`II-C`}:

Each of a new column **is just an elementwise multiplication of corresponding base columns**

```
    I-A I-B I-C II-A  II-B  II-C
 0   2   2   3    0    0      0
 1   0   0   0    2    2      3
 2   0   0   0    0    0      0
 3   2   3   4    2    3      4
```

ATM i dont have any working solution. I'am trying to use loops(not succeding in this), but i hope there's more sufficient way.

Comment: I've added the numpy tag because it might be much easier with numpy's broadcasting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple, really. You have two sets of columns that you want to combine pairwise. I won't even bother with permutation tools:

```
>>> new_df = pd.DataFrame()
>>>
>>> for i in ["I", "II"]:
        for a in ["A", "B", "C"]:
            new_df[i+"-"+a] = df[i] * df[a]
>>> new_df
   I-A  I-B  I-C  II-A  II-B  II-C
0    2    2    3     0     0     0
1    0    0    0     2     2     3
2    0    0    0     0     0     0
3    2    3    4     2     3     4
```

Of course you could obtain the lists of column names as slices off `df.columns`, or in whatever other way is convenient. E.g. for your example dataframe you could write

```
>>> for i in df.columns[3:]:
        for a in df.columns[:3]:
            new_df[i+"-"+a] = df[i] * df[a]
```

Comment: wow! Could you please add code, how to avoid explict use of column names. I guess, with the help of the slices, please?

Answer (score 0):

Using loops, you can use this code. It's definitely not the most elegant solution but should work for your purpose. It only requires that you specify the columns that you'd like to use for the pairwise multiplication. It seems to be quite readable though, which is something you may want.

```
def element_wise_mult(first, second):

    element_wise_mult = []
    for i, el in enumerate(first):
        element_wise_mult.append(el * second[i])

    return element_wise_mult


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,2,1,2],
                       'B':[2,2,3,3],
                       'C':[3,3,3,4],
                       'I':[1,0,0,1],
                      'II':[0,1,0,1]})


    fs = ['I', 'II']
    sc = ['A', 'B', 'C']

    series = []
    names = []

    for i in fs:
        for j in sc:
            names.append(i + '-' + j)
            series.append(pd.Series(element_wise(df[i], df[j])))  # append array creates as a pandas series

   print(pd.DataFrame(series, index=names).T)    # reconstruct dataframe from the series and names stored
```

Returns:

```
   I-A  I-B  I-C  II-A  II-B  II-C
0    2    2    3     0     0     0
1    0    0    0     2     2     3
2    0    0    0     0     0     0
3    2    3    4     2     3     4
```

Comment: Thanks,I will check this out tomorrow

Comment: @Carlo you don't need it with `pandas`, but elementwise multiplication should use `zip`: `product = [ a*b for a,b in zip(first, second) ]`

Comment: @alexis definitely. I can update that, although your solution would still be both more readable and elegant :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without for loops for your specific example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,2,1,2],
                   'B':[2,2,3,3],
                   'C':[3,3,3,4],
                   'I':[1,0,0,1],
                   'II':[0,1,0,1]})
cross_vals=np.tile(df[df.columns[:3]].values,(1,2))*np.repeat(df[df.columns[3:]].values,3,axis=1)
cros_cols=np.repeat(df.columns[3:].values,3)+np.array('-')+np.tile(df.columns[:3].values,(1,2))
new_df=pd.DataFrame(cross_vals,columns=cros_cols[0])
```

Then `new_df` is

```
   I-A  I-B I-C II-A II-B II-C
0   2    2   3   0    0    0
1   0    0   0   2    2    3
2   0    0   0   0    0    0
3   2    3   4   2    3    4
```

You could generalize it to any size as long as the columns `A,B,C,...` are consecutive and similarly the columns `I,II,...` are consecutive.

For the general case, if the columns are not necessarily consecutive, you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[2,2,1,2],
                       'B':[2,2,3,3],
                       'C':[3,3,3,4],
                       'I':[1,0,0,1],
                       'II':[0,1,0,1]})
let=np.array(['A','B','C'],dtype=object)
num=np.array(['I','II'],dtype=object)
cross_vals=np.tile(df[let].values,(1,len(num)))*np.repeat(df[num].values,len(let),axis=1)
cros_cols=np.repeat(num,len(let))+np.array('-')+np.tile(let,(1,len(num)))
new_df=pd.DataFrame(cross_vals,columns=cros_cols[0])
```

And the result is the same as above.

Comment: In python 3 this ends with:`AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'matlib'`

Comment: Yes you are right, it runs on python2 but not python3. I replaced it with np.tile which work on both python2 and python3 (the syntax is a bit different, so I updated my solution).

Comment: Thanks, i will check this out!